# How to send data in flutter with invokeMethod in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, flutter

I'm developing an app with flutter and native (java, objc).

In Android (using java), we passed data to flutter with `channel.invokeMethod()`.

```
static MethodChannel channel;

public static void GetTransData(int nTrans1, int nTrans2, int nTrans3){
        Map<String, Integer> data = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        data.put("Trans1", nTrans1);
        data.put("Trans2", nTrans2);
        data.put("Trans3", nTrans3);

        channel.invokeMethod("GetTransData", data);
    }
```

But when I try to use `invokeMethod()` on ios (using objective-c) I get an error saying `Property 'invokeMethod' not found on object of type 'FlutterMethodChannel *'.

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"value2", nil];
[data setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:101] forKey:@"value1"];
[data setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:202] forKey:@"value2"];

          
CHANNEL.invokeMethod(@"iosMethodCallTest", data); //Property 'invokeMethod' not found on object of type 'FlutterMethodChannel *'
```

Is there a way to send data via `invokeMehtod()` from `objective-c` to flutter??? The reason for using this method is that the logic of `objc` needs to transfer data in the middle. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

You can do this by using `invokeMethod:arguments` of `FlutterMethodChannel`.

```
[CHANNEL invokeMethod:@"iosMethodCallTest" arguments:data];
```